# Creating Folder Failed on jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I click "New" to create text file,folder, and python3 file on jupyter notebook, it shows that "Creating File Failed" and "An error occurred while creating a new file". Could you please give me some advice about how to solve this problem ? The screenshot is attached. Thank you very much !

**Some details**: I use `pip install jupyter` to install ***jupyter notebook*** in ***Linux environment***. You can see from the attached screenshot that there is a **new** icon near to the **upload** icon on the upper right, then I click the black upside-down triangle on the **new** icon, then I choose **folder**. This is the process in which I try to create a new folder on **jupyter notebook**.

[image]

Comment: You need to run notebook as admin or be sure that you have privileges to put that folder where you are trying. What command did you use to start notebook?

Comment: @W.Dodge I open notebook by typing **jupyter notebook** in the terminal. Could you please provide some details for me ? Thank you very much !

Comment: you can run `jupyter notebook --allow-root` to allow sudo privileges

Comment: @W.Dodge I feel so sorry that it does not work !

Comment: Try editing your question to include: the steps you took to install your notebook, your OS, and tell us where you are trying to create a folder. Those details will help

Comment: @W.Dodge I have added some details, hope that you can give me some advice. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the `--user` tag with `pip`

The reason you cannot create a folder is because you do not have permission. This could be that you are not a on the `sudo` list or that you are not the owner of the folder where you are trying to create a new folder.

You can potentially avoid these problems by removing your jupyter install and re-installing with the '--user' option. Be sure that you have configured a non root user with `sudo` privileges and that you are logged in as that user. Try the following:

```
pip uninstall jupyter
pip install jupyter --user
```

Run notebook as usual:

```
jupyter notebook
```

One more thing, be sure that you are trying to create a folder in your home directory. If you are user "Bob", make sure you are creating the folder in `/home/bob/` You are the owner of this directory and should be able to modify it as you wish.

Further reading:

[link1](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions)
[link2](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !! I will also try your method !

Answer (score 0):

I have found reasons that I cannot create new folder/file on jupyter notebook. Reason is that I directly open jupyter notebook in the anaconda3 environment, that's incorrect! Intuitive description is that I should switch from `/home/${USER}/anaconda3` to `/home/${USER}/anaconda3/bin`, because when I use `whereis jupyter`, I find that jupyter is under `/~/bin` directory. So, I have a try and succeed !

Comment: If you have the same question, please try my method. Although I am not sure whether it will work for your case, you can have a try !